# How to add the iteration number based on a condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the table with the columns ***Product*** and ***Status*** and want to create a third column named ***Values*** as seen below:

| Product | Status | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 1 |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| a | 1 | 3 |
| b | 0 | 1 |
| b | 1 | 2 |
| b | 1 | 3 |
| b | 0 | 3 |
| b | 0 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 4 |

I want ***Values*** to be the cumulative sum of the values in ***Status***, but starting from **1** instead of **0**. I also want this to be performed grouped by ***Product***.

This is my SAS code to do this:

```
if first.product then do; 
    values = 1;
end; 
if status = 1 then do; 
    values = values + 1; 
end;
```

Here is code to generate the table.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'Status': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
}).set_index('Product')
```

Expected output:

```py
expected_output = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'Status': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'Values': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}).set_index('Product')
```

Comment: we are going to need some more information to be able to help. What is the code you are actually writing? What have you written so far? What are you getting with your code and what do you want? you say you want that output, but what is your input?

Stack Overflow works best when you have already written code and have a specific issue with it, rather than very broad questions like this.

Comment: Can you please provide more context or details about what you're trying to achieve with this dataset?
How exactly do you want the 'Values' column to be increased based on the 'Status' column? Could you give an example?
Are you looking for a specific programming language or tool to accomplish this task?

Comment: when working with the data in python are you using something like pandas or a more primitive structure like a list of dictionaries?

Comment: My input dataset is same as above expect the values column.

As I'm doing the Python (Pandas) transition. I have just shared the sample dataset.
My SAS code is:

if first.product then do; values =1; end;
if status = 1 then do; values = values + 1; end;

The above two condition are in the SAS loop with some other new column creation. I'm stuck with this 'Values' criteria alone.

Answer (score -1):

```py
df['Values'] = df.groupby('Product').cumcount() + 1
```

Here is some code to test it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'Status': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
})


expected_output = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'Status': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'Values': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
})

assert all(df == expected_output)
```

Comment: Why do you use `.set_index('Product')` as this is not representative of OP data format?

Comment: Someone else, not me downvoting; your answer works fine and now produces the expected ouput.